# $68\%$ of values will be between $-1$ and $1$ SD, how come that the true mean is much more precise with $95\%$ CI?

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I am sorry for a possibly confusing title. I do not get the following (using an example from mathisfun.com):

1. In a sample of 40 men, we get a mean height of 175 cm. The standard deviation is 20 cm. If I get it right, then (assuming normal distribution), 68% of men will have a height between 155 and 195 cm (i.e. from - 1 SD to + 1 SD). Is that true?
2. Now calculating the 95% **confidence interval**, the result will be 175 ± 6.2 cm. As 95% CI uses the Z value of 1.96, it is pretty much 2 SDs. I just do not get it - if 68% of men will have their height between 155 and 195 (± 1 SD), I would expect that with 2 SDs, it should be between 135 and 205!
   What I am missing please?

A page where I am reffering to, with the explanation and formulas:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/confidence-interval.html

EDIT: In the following example, the interval is calculated without dividing by the number of subjects:

> 140 children had a mean urinary lead concentration of 2.18 µmol24hr,
> with standard deviation 0.87. The points that include 95% of the
> observations are 2.18 ± (1.96 × 0.87), giving a range of 0.48 to 3.89

Comment: in (2) where do you get $175 \pm 6.2$ from?

Comment: looks like an arithmetic error somewhere? can you explain where 6.2 comes from?

Comment: @CutePoison I do not know how to correctly enter formulas here, but using the standard one for CI: X +- Z * s/sqrt(n)

Comment: @gt6989b Here the page where they explain, the calculation is correct, other online calculators bring the same results: https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/confidence-interval.html

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

You are mistaking the distribution of the *data* and the distribution of the *mean*.

Assuming the data of the men is indeed normally distributed, then 68% of the men in your sample would have a height between $\mu \pm 1 \sigma = 175 \pm 20$.

But if we want to find the range of the *true* mean that have "generated" the data, we need to create a confidence interval for the *mean*.

For the *mean* you need to use the formular

$[CI_{-}, CI_{+}] = [\mu- Z\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}, \mu + Z\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}]$.

See the full example below for both cases:

$\mu = 175$

$\sigma =20$

$n = 40$

and the fomular

and your Z-value for a 68% CI is almost 1, (`qnorm(1-(1-0.68)/2)` in R for the correct value) thus the 68% CI interval is

$175 \pm \frac{20}{\sqrt{40}} = [171.84,178.16]$

where the 95% is

$175 \pm 1.96 \cdot \frac{20}{\sqrt{40}} = [168.8,181.2] = 1.75\pm 6.2$

As we can see, the 95% is greater than the 68% as expected

Comment: Thanks, I still do not completely understand: what is the difference between standard normal and the one in the example? Why 68% with SD of 20 does not result in 155 and 195 (175 +- 20?}

Comment: because you do not need to add 20, but $20/\sqrt{40}$ as in the example

Comment: Where do you get the +- 20 from and not $\pm 20/\sqrt{40}$ ?

Comment: Well from the basic normal distribution knowledge: I know the mean and I know the SD, therefore the values within -1SD and 1SD are the mean +- 20. Because there are other examples (e.g. defining laboratory ranges) where you do not divide by the number of samples/observations, and I do not understand why.

Comment: I edited the original question and added at the end an example from a book where the range is defined without dividing by the number of elements,

Comment: I have editted it - you are mixing the *data* and the *mean of the data*